# How can retrieve / decode html utf-8 character with unicode?

Tags: html, unicode, utf-8, decode, font-face

When I try to visit any website which is integrated with unicode हिंदी text then browser display that contain like...
¤ªà¤•à¥�à¤·à¥€ à¤•à¥‡ à¤ªà¤¾à¤¸ à¤µà¥‹à¤¸à¤¾à¤°à¥€ à¤¸à¥�à¤– à¤¸à¥�à¤µà¤¿à¤§à¤¾à¤�à¤� à¤¹à¥ˆà¤‚, à¤œà¥‹ à¤‰à¤¨à¤•à¥‡ à¤œà

How to decode this character and convert it into pure unicode?

Comment: � is an indication that the wrong character encoding was used to decode bytes to text. The original text is not recoverable from that point. You have to go upstream to whatever is reading with a character encoding other than what the writer used. I hope this helps. Your question is unclear. Please [edit].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is UTF-8 encoded Devanagari wrongly displayed as Windows-1252. If you reverse the direction, e.g.

```
piconv -f utf-8 -t windows-1252 -s '¤ªà¤•à¥�à¤·à¥€ à¤•à¥‡ à¤ªà¤¾à¤¸ à¤µà¥‹à¤¸à¤¾à¤°à¥€ à¤¸à¥�à¤– à¤¸à¥�à¤µà¤¿à¤§à¤¾à¤�à¤� à¤¹à¥ˆà¤‚, à¤œà¥‹ à¤‰à¤¨à¤•à¥‡ à¤œà'
```

then you get parts of the original text back:

```
��क��?षी के पास वोसारी स��?ख स��?विधा��?��? हैं, जो उनके ज�
```

Your copy-paste operation made decoding here lossy. Redirect input into a file instead of copy-paste so that you do not introduce any defects.

[piconv](https://perldoc.pl/piconv) ships with Perl.